# PyQt dialog focus when called from JS+Python

Tags: python, html, dialog, focus, pyqt

I've a HTML window with a button that calls a python function that loads a PyQT Dialog.
My Problem is: my nice Dialog appears behind the HTML window and the user has to move the HTML window in order to use the PyQT GUI.
Where should I define, and how do I define the Dialog (PyQt) to be above the HTML window?
Thanks!

More information:

my python file imports:
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

my HTML button calls python function using JSON.
The python functions opens my Dialog:

```
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
ui = Ui_Dialog()
ui.setupUi(Dialog)
Dialog.setModal(True)       
Dialog.show()
Dialog.raise_()
app.exec_()
```

Clicking the HTML button that located in my HTML page, opens my DIALOG, but, the DIALOG appears behind the HTML page.

Please let me know what is the missing information I should add to my Q.
Thank you :)
Dolphinet

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `.raise()_` on your PyQt window.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, it is still not work, here is my code:
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) ; 
Dialog = QtGui.QDialog() ; 
ui = Ui_Dialog() ; 
ui.setupUi(Dialog) ; 
Dialog.setModal(True) ; 
Dialog.raise_() ; 
Dialog.show() ;   
app.exec_() ; 
  ...I guess I'm doing something wrong and any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

[`raise_()`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qwidget.html#raise) brings the window on top.

Or use `exec_()` to show it as a [modal dialog](http://qt-project.org/doc/qdialog.html#modal-dialogs)

Comment: thanks for reply, I tried both, I put the code in my comment below.
please advice,
Thank you again.

Comment: your example only has one widget, there is nothing the dialog can be put in front of. try this: http://pastebin.com/SJBu0aT6 - or what exactly are you trying to do? maybe some reald code would help.

Comment: Hi, In the front I have an HTML web page.
Im calling the Dialog from an HTML Button.
As a result - my HTML in the front and the Dialog is behind.
Any advice?

Comment: Are you using `QtWebKit`? You should edit your question to include some example of how you're showing your dialog.

Comment: Thanks again, I edited my Q, please let me know if there is still missing information.

Comment: still a few things that aren't clear: is this a web application? your taling about json and http, so you probably have some webserver serving content. why would you want to launch a qt gui on a server? the user won't see it. and for the rest, probably the window manager is preventing focus stealing when the program is lounched from a background process, it hasn't really anything to do with Qt itself.

Comment: The project Im working on is indeed web. There is a webserver that runs with Python, Json, Jinja2, and more....
In addition there is a ready tool, written in python+PyQT and we need to connect them by HTML-Button-Click.
I click the button and a thread is created, running the PyQT Dialog.
When done, user should keep his working on the web.
All seems to work fine, but, the Dialog appears behind the Web application and user should manually "bring" the focus to the Dialog.

Comment: I suspect what you see is the [focus stealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_stealing) prevention of your window manager ([which is a good thing](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/please-dont-steal-my-focus.html)). I'm afraid I can't provide you with a solution, you can alway google for [similar problems](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=64&t=89632), but there probably won't be a solution working for any window manager. That's one reason why mixing different GUI Technologies can be bad.

Comment: Hi again. I decided to change the way I use the pyQT Dialog launching:
Till now I opened it in a separate Thread. I changed it to  be on same Thread and now I see it in the front... I also think like you - that there was no solution for my problem and Im happy that finally I found a way to have this Dialog to be in the front....
The price of my solution is that the HTML application does noting till user finishing his work on the Dialog. I can live with that...
Thank you all for you advices.
Wish you a nice day
~Dolphinet~